# Jest throwing reference error about an import inside a node_modules dependency

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I have a nestjs monorepo application with working tests via Jest. This is in relation to the global unit tests which take their configuration from the nestjs CLI-created configuration within package.json.

My storage.service.ts uses `jimp` in one of its methods to resize an image.

This has `@jimp/types` dependency that depends on `@jimp/gif` which depends on `gifwrap`.

For every test that runs in my console, I see this error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at node_modules/.pnpm/gifwrap@0.9.2/node_modules/gifwrap/src/gifcodec.js:7:15
```

I'm also using beforeAll() and afterAll() hook to close the nestjs module.

Jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/",
      "<rootDir>/libs/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
...
```

How can I silence this error or perhaps even be as bold as fixing it?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: any luck on this one man?

Comment: sadly no, I believe downgrading to another typescript version, specifically `4.0.6` and using `yarn` instead of `pnpm` temporarily fixed the issue but not a permanent solution

Comment: Im using JS not TS and it is also happening to me, i've updated the `jimp` version from `0.10.x` to `0.16.1`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and the issue occurs only if the test is synchronous.
A minimal timeout solves the problem:

```js
afterAll(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
});
```

or

```js
afterAll(done => {
  setTimeout(done);
});
```

Comment: I've added `afterAll(done => { setTimeout(done); });` to my `setupTest.js` so this apply that code globally to all unit tests changing only one file and it solved my problem

Comment: For my case, I have to user `afterEach` rather than `afterAll` for the error to go away.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring the `timers` in jest config to `modern` solved the problem for me: [jest-docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#timers-string)

```
"timers": "modern",
```

Comment: This solved it for me too. Even using jest.useFakeTimers("modern") didn't work, but this did.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help your case, but the way I solved it in my typescript project is by mocking the jimp import itself. I was testing a class that used some classes that contained Jimp. Instead of mocking all of those, mocking jimp was easier.

```
jest.mock('jimp', () => {
  return {};
}
```

I put this below my imports and before my tests. Depending on what you're doing, you might need to go deeper in your mock as well. Example:

```
jest.mock('jimp', () => {
  return {
    read: jest.fn().mockImplementation(),
  };
});
```

I did it on jest 25, but I assume it works in most other versions as well.

My jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: 'src',
  testRegex: '\\.spec\\.ts$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['e2e/'],
  coverageDirectory: '../coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};

process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
  APP_ENV: 'development',
});
```